# Using Linq to Entity how can I check if User exists and is Active with given UserName, Password and Active field

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I relatively new to Linq and need to use it to query an Entity's table to see if  provided UserName and Password exist and Active field is set to 1.

This is my DataBase entity:

```
public partial class DatabaseEntities : DbContext
{
   public DataBaseEntities() : base("name=DataBaseEntities"){}  

   public virtual DbSet<UserSvc> UserSvc { get; set; }
}
```

This is my User model:

```
public partial class UserSvc
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public static UserSvc Authenticate(int userName, string Password, bool isActive)
    {
        using (var ctx = new DataBaseEntities())
        {
             return (UserSvc)ctx.UserSvc.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == userName && u.Password == Password && u.Active);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: DbSet<tblUser> is actually compiling? shouldn't it be DbSet<User>? then its simply ctx.tblUser.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.UserName==userName&&x.Password==Password&&x.Active);

Comment: Also, referencing the context from within the model breaks SoC. Keep your model POCO and move business rules to a helper or business layer.

Comment: But how do I return User type from that query? Please see the updated code

Comment: Please show `User` class, it's different of `UserSvc`, right?

Comment: My mistake, I meant UserSvc. See updated code

Comment: I don't understand what is your issue, can you clarify? Also there is not need to cast and you should not save password as a plain text in your DB